# Tizen native to javascript data transfer

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I know **Javascriptbridge** to send data from js to **tizen**.

```
Is there any way to pass data from native to javascript
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use EvaluateJavascriptN method from web control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MessagePort API](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/messageport.html). The [programming guide](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/io_guide/messageport.htm) says:

> Tizen Web applications can communicate with other Web or native
>   applications using the MessagePort API. The message data type for the
>   communication is map data, which consists of a string key and value
>   pair.